How to properly input mp files in MetaFun?
In my ConTeXt project I have a long .mp file that I want to divide into several sub-files and make it library-like. For that purpose I load the initial file with
\startMPinclusions
  input path/to/file.mp;
\stopMPinclusions

which usually works great.
Now, I have several MetaPost/MetaFun files in path/to/ and want to load them in file.mp with:
input abc.mp;
input cde.mp;

However, I get the following error:
metapost        > trace > This is MPLIB for LuaMetaTeX, version 3.15, running in double mode.
metapost        > trace >
metapost        > trace > loading metafun for lmtx, including the plain 1.004 base definitions
metapost        > trace >
metafun         > log >
metafun         > log > error: Emergency stop
metafun         > log >
metapost        > trace > <insert>
metafun         > log >
metafun         > log > invalid input file
metafun         > log >
metapost        > trace > <line 1> input abc.mp ;
metapost        > trace >

Is there a way to load those files? Am I doing it wrong?
Here is the best example ever: fill-drawing a circle with a given radius:
./main.tex:
\startMPinclusions
  input library/file.mp;
\stopMPinclusions

\starttext
  \startMPcode
    draw_circle(5cm) ;
  \stopMPcode
\stoptext

./library/file.mp:
input abc.mp ;

./library/abc.mp:
vardef draw_circle(expr radius) =
  filldraw fullcircle scaled (2*radius) ;
enddef ;


You want the \usepath command:
$ tree -al
.
├── library
│   ├── abc.mp
│   └── file.mp
└── main.tex

2 directories, 3 files

$ cat main.tex

\usepath[library]

\startMPinclusions
    input library/file.mp;
\stopMPinclusions

\startMPpage[offset=1ex]
    draw_circle(5cm) ;
\stopMPpage


